# iframe not displaying properly ios iphone

Tags: html, iframe

Question: what might be the cause of the iframe not working properly only on IOS, iphone? 
It seems like it's zooming in automatically, but that is not the intention 
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the viewport issue to me.

I've seen this before... Here is a solution that might work for you in this case.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Add/modify this tag in your  and let me know if it works.

Note that by doing this you will be removing the option for the user to pinch and zoom on your site. Most the time you don't have to care about that but some users depend on the functionality.

Comment: thanks for helping me, but it's still not working... Is there maybe another explanation for this?

Comment: @JeroenElzinga Really hard to diagnose without the code or a link to the site/page

Comment: this is the website name: https://www.workshopsafety.nl/ where the iframe is glitching on iphone ios. And this is the iframe website: http://dealermarketingservices.nl/reditex/